# Running an existing project under Symfony framework

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I'm new to the symfony framework and not good at php, and I've come to task of running an existing backup of project.

To get in touch with it, I've run a debian 8 server on virtual machine locally.
To make sure I know how symfony works I decided to run the symfony demo.
The problem is I'm not sure if I'm configuring it well with apache2, as I've followed the guide on symfony's site.

I've installed the symfony demo under `/var/www/html/symfony_demo`

This is my sites-avaliable

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony_demo/web
    <Directory /var/www/symfony_demo/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've executed `php bin/console server:start` from the `symfony_demo` directory.

Web server is up and running on the default `127.0.0.1:8000`.

When trying to access the apache2 default `index.html` before the changes to `sites-avaliable`, under :80 it was all okay. My `192.168.0.100` was accessible just okay from the browser. But after changing the configuration, and trying to get to `192.168.0.100:8000` I get unable to connect.

I need help troubleshooting this because I dont know where to seek for problem. Ask anything.

Comment: Well you have your own apache2 server so you don not need the build in webserver. What happens if you go to http://domain.tld/app_dev.php ?

Comment: I killed the build in webserver, and accordingly trying to access 192.168.0.100/app_dev.php responds with 404.

Comment: Okay, i actually made it to the point of reaching app_dev.php which prints

You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.


What to do from this point?

Comment: app_dev.php only works on localhost by default.

Answer (score 0):

See your `.htaccess` config in the `/var/www/symfony_demo/web` directory and look if `app.php` is config as `DirectoryIndex`. Maybe you need to add `DirectoyIndex` to your config because Apache is searching for `index.html` or `index.php` but not for `app.php`:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony_demo/web
    <Directory /var/www/symfony_demo/web>
        DirectoryIndex app.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

What to do from this point?

edit app_dev.php ( as mentionned is your error )

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

add your ip to

```
|| !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
```

or comment th whole block